# Jquery with <ul><li> display fine in Firefox, but not Opera & Chrome

Tags: jquery, html-lists

This also happens with many themes that I've tried. Don't know whether it is normal behavior or not. Can anyone explain this for me?

Opera:

[opera http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7433/screenshot085vt.png](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7433/screenshot085vt.png)

Chrome:

[Chrome http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/4260/screenshot084.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/4260/screenshot084.png)

Firefox:

[Firefox http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3470/screenshot083a.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3470/screenshot083a.png)

Comment: I think you are including image(`<img scr='path' />`) here with incorrect path for each <li>. Firefox is just hiding it.

Comment: yeah. firefox hides the arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an IMG tag in there to display an image, and the image file is missing.

Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS code that you are using?

Comment: thks. I've found out that in the "jqueryslidemenu.js" file, the src of image is not correct and fixed it. Now it displays normally